# Scala PlayJson Cyclic Reference

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, play-json

**Context**

I have a case class which is an item in a hierarchy, which refers to itself like so:

```
case class Node(
  name:     String,
  children: Option[Seq[Node]] = None
)
```

I would like a PlayJson [`Format`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) for this.

Usually, you can just do:

```
implicit lazy val formatter = Json.format[MyCaseClass]
```

But this doesn't work.

Why?

PlayJson uses a Scala macro to produce a `Format` for the case class, it will go through all fields, when it gets to the field `children` it will look for an existing formatter for `Node` which it hasn't constructed yet, ending with a compilation error:

```
No implicit format for Option[Seq[Node]] available.
[error]   implicit lazy val formatter = Json.format[Node]
```

---

**Questions**

What's the best way to approach this?
Is this a known issue with PlayJson format macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that can be found under `recursive types` in play-json [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#recursive-types):

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.{Reads, Writes, _}

case class Node(name: String, children: Option[Seq[Node]] = None)

implicit lazy val nodeReads: Reads[Node] = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] and
  (__ \ "children").lazyReadNullable(Reads.seq[Node](nodeReads))
)(Node)

implicit lazy val nodeWrites: Writes[Node] = (
  (__ \ "name").write[String] and
  (__ \ "children").lazyWriteNullable(Writes.seq[Node](nodeWrites))
)(unlift(Node.unapply))
```

Since in that case `Reads` and `Writes` are symmetrical, you can create the whole thing as a single `Format`:

```
implicit lazy val nodeFormat: Format[Node] = (
  (__ \ "name").format[String] and
  (__ \ "children").lazyFormatNullable(Reads.seq[Node](nodeFormat), Writes.seq[Node](nodeFormat))
)(Node.apply, unlift(Node.unapply))
```

Comment: Check out my edit, the whole thing could be shortened a little.

Comment: Seems like something which should be internalised to the macro. I haven't played with my own macro in Scala just yet; is there something specific about Scala macro's which means this isn't possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't played with my own macros as well, so I'm not able to answer that ;)

Comment: What if I have case class as below.
`case class Check(string:String)`

`case class Node(name: String, children: Option[Node] = None, anotherChildren:Check)`