# Use Play framework to read JSON with recursive list of sealed traits

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I've got some JSON that I need to parse, and my project already uses Play, so that seems like the right place to start.

Given these definitions:

```
sealed trait Thing
case class Foo(i: Int) extends Thing
case class Bar(s: String, t: List[Thing]) extends Thing
```

I would want this JSON:

```
{
  s: "doomy doomy doom",
  t: [ 24, { s: "doooom!", t: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }, 42, 126 ]
}
```

To become this object:

```
Bar("doomy doomy doom", List(Foo(24), Bar("doooom!", List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))), Foo(42), Foo(126)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Recursive-Types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596492/scala-play-json-nested-cyclic-dependency-json-parsing ?

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin Thanks for your suggestion. One of my sticking points is that any element of the list could be either a `Foo` or a `Bar`, which that question doesn't address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @dmytro-mitin answer, you can use Scala's [value class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) for `Foo`. [Play JSON documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) includes Reads/Writes/Formats for value classes. Then you can use `Int` instead of an object with single field in your original example. Here is an updated example with a value class:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

sealed trait Thing extends Any

object Thing {
  implicit val thingReads: Reads[Thing] = Foo.fooReads.or[Thing](Bar.barReads.widen)

  implicit val thingWrites: Writes[Thing] = {
    case f: Foo => Foo.fooWrites.writes(f)
    case b: Bar => Bar.barWrites.writes(b)
  }
}

case class Foo(i: Int) extends AnyVal with Thing

object Foo {
  implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = Json.valueReads[Foo]
  implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] = Json.valueWrites[Foo]
}

case class Bar(s: String, t: List[Thing]) extends Thing

object Bar {
  implicit val barReads: Reads[Bar] = (
    (__ \ "s").read[String] and
      (__ \ "t").lazyRead(Reads.list[Thing](Thing.thingReads))
  )(Bar.apply _)

  implicit val barWrites: Writes[Bar] = (
    (__ \ "s").write[String] and
      (__ \ "t").lazyWrite(Writes.list[Thing](Thing.thingWrites))
  )(unlift(Bar.unapply))
}

val thing: Thing = Bar("doom", List(Foo(12), Bar("doom", List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)))))
val json = Json.toJson(thing)
val str = Json.stringify(json)
// {"s":"doom","t":[12,{"s":"doom","t":[1,2,3]}]}
val thing1 = Json.parse(str).as[Thing]
// Bar(doom,List(Foo(12), Bar(doom,List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)))))
thing1 == thing // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define custom codecs for the trait (without discriminator) and lazy codecs for the recursive type

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

sealed trait Thing
object Thing {
  implicit val thingReads: Reads[Thing] = Foo.fooReads.or[Thing](Bar.barReads.widen)

  implicit val thingWrites: OWrites[Thing] = {
    case x: Foo => Foo.fooWrites.writes(x)
    case x: Bar => Bar.barWrites.writes(x)
  }
}

case class Foo(i: Int) extends Thing
object Foo {
  implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = Json.reads[Foo]
  implicit val fooWrites: OWrites[Foo] = Json.writes[Foo]
}

case class Bar(s: String, t: List[Thing]) extends Thing
object Bar {
  implicit val barReads: Reads[Bar] = (
    (__ \ "s").read[String] and
      (__ \ "t").lazyRead(Reads.list[Thing](Thing.thingReads))
  )(Bar.apply _)

  implicit val barWrites: OWrites[Bar] = (
    (__ \ "s").write[String] and
      (__ \ "t").lazyWrite(Writes.list[Thing](Thing.thingWrites))
  )(unlift(Bar.unapply))
}

val thing: Thing = Bar("doomy doomy doom", List(Foo(24), Bar("doooom!", List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))), Foo(42), Foo(126)))
val str = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(thing))
//{"s":"doomy doomy doom","t":[{"i":24},{"s":"doooom!","t":[{"i":1},{"i":2},{"i":3}]},{"i":42},{"i":126}]}
val thing1 = Json.parse(str).as[Thing]
// Bar(doomy doomy doom,List(Foo(24), Bar(doooom!,List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))), Foo(42), Foo(126)))
thing1 == thing // true
```

[Scala play json nested cyclic dependency json parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596492/scala-play-json-nested-cyclic-dependency-json-parsing)